# Unity 2D - Weapon doesn't switch to left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simple 2D scene where I move left/right on the X axis and jump/fall on the Y axis. Anyway, I set the weapon to face right by default. I made it a child of the player, but when I use the left arrow or the A key the weapon doesn't switch sides. No real surprise there though.

I'm confused on how to approach this switch of transition.

```
 public GameObject gun; // define the gun object
```

then inside a function

```
 getComponent<GameObject>(); //Which I may not need to do ?
```

inside my movement script:

```
if(GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){

    gun.transform.position = player.position.rotate; // ??? 
 }
```

For some reason I cannot think of how to simply reverse lol WHY ME ???

Comment: please describe your situation more clearly. you know what you mean by "face right" and "switch sides" but the rest of us don't understand. if you want to change the gun's rotation use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: Setting `gun.transform.position` sets the gun's position, not the direction it is facing.

Comment: Okay, my apologies about that. I'm designing a 2D game. My weapon faces to the right of the screen by default; it's attached to my player character. However, when I move to the left, my player turns and faces the left of the screen. Unfortunately, the weapon faces to the right of the screen still.

Comment: Where is your player turn code?

Comment: Sounds like you are just trying to mirror over the y axis. you can just change the localscale.x to -1

Comment: do you perhaps want `gun.transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation`?

Comment: @Programmer - I posted my turn code above.  I can use either "A" or "LeftArrow" to turn. "D" or "RightArrow" to move right.

Comment: @ryeMoss - Hmm, interesting. How would I go about implementing the localscale.x ? gun.transform.position = gun.transform.position.localscale.x(-1);

Comment: How do you turn your player? if the gun game object is the child of player, after the player turns to left, the gun turns left too without any code. But for example, if you want to turn gun to left, you can use this code: `gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);`

Comment: @TimDuval most straightforward would just be `gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);`

Comment: @ryeMoss - I gave that a try but it caused the gun to turn into a cube shape and it fires towards the Zaxis. Any thoughts of why that occurred?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi - Yes, the gun and it's components are all children objects to the player. Which is why this baffled me. I thought it would have turned with it too! Sadly, it faces only to the right, and when I implemented the code provided, the gun turned into a cube shape that fires towards the Z axis. Weird!

Comment: @TimDuval Ok. Can you give me all your scripts of player and gun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new variable `isFacingRight` to keep track of existing facing. And as mentioned by others you flip the localscale to change the direction.

```
bool isFacingRight = true;

void Update(){
    //other stuff

    if(GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        FaceLeft();
    }    
    if(GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        FaceRight();
    }    
}

void FaceRight(){
    if(!isFacingRight){
        gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        isFacingRight = true;
    }
}

void FaceLeft(){
    if(isFacingRight){
        gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        isFacingRight = false;
    }
}
```

********************* SOLVED ******************************

I duplicated my weapon and flipped it to the left facing side. I manually clicked the deactivate checkbox on the left-facing weapon. Here's the code I used:

```
public GameObject gun = Pshoot.gun; // Right facing gun
public GameObject gun1 = Pshoot.gun1; // Left facing gun

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
       GetComponent<Renderer>().material = rgtFace;
        gun.SetActive(false);
        gun1.SetActive(true);
       // isFacingRight = false;
       // FaceLeft();
      // gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,-1);
    }
```

In this left movement check, I set the right gun to false and activated the left gun to appear. (Ignore the commented out portion, I learned localeScale today so I'm keeping it for later reference. YOU may not need it so ignore it)

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = lftFace;
        gun.SetActive(true);
        gun1.SetActive(false);
       // isFacingRight = true;
    }
```

Above is the code for setting the right facing gun up. Now just a heads up, you wont need the material code. That's just something I done to animate my sprite. You'll notice it says lftFace above but I accidentally put the right face image in the leftface variable lol it doesn't affect the game and I can live with it. Don't judge me! :p

Anyway, thanks to all who commented to help me! Much love cyber programmer fam!

Comment: Okay, I like your approach! I modified the code a bit because I don't need right face at this time. Here's what I did (But honestly, I can probably achieve the same thing without the function but whatever lol it's ok)

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || 
        Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
           GetComponent<Renderer>().material = rgtFace;
            isFacingRight = false;
            FaceLeft();
          // gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,-1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || 
       Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {

            GetComponent<Renderer>().material = lftFace;
            isFacingRight = true;
        }

Comment: void FaceLeft() {

        gun.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);

    }

Comment: However, the issue now is it turns my weapon into a cube shape and fires away from the camera towards the backdrop. Basically my character is a cube with a face. The gun is a cube, sphere, and an empty that spawns bullets (Bullets are spheres). I don't know that I rotated any of these objects off their axis. would it even matter? The code works, but my gun is buggy...

Comment: If you have multiple objects as gun then first create a parent gameobject that has all your gun cubes and spheres in it. And then trying flipping that gameobject

Comment: Also it might be helpful to watch some 2d gun flipping tutorials like this one [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHQyPgccD4M)

Comment: I was able to fix it by duplicating the gun, spinning it to the left, and using SetActive(). I'm about to post the code up top in my opening post so other can see. Thanks to all whom replied! Y'all rock!